# Why does this graph give me a real part and an imaginary part?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I don't understand why I get 2 curves when plotting $e^{ix}$. This is probably very simple for most mathematicians, but I never really learned why. Sometimes when I plot other things I also get a real and imaginary part from Wolfram Alpha, but I never understood why.

[image]

Comment: Because $i$ stands for the imaginary unit?

Comment: Even though it does, in my naivety I would only expect the imaginary curve, not the real curve.

Comment: $e^{ix}$ is a complex function that outputs complex numbers.  Complex numbers are 2-dimensional with a real part and an imaginary part. Thus the graph would need three dimensions to represent (the x-axis for the {ix} input.  A y-axis for the real part of the complex output and a z-axis for the imaginary part of the complex output).  As that isn't possible in a flat display Wolfram displays the real and complex outputs on the same axis but different colors.)

Comment: "Even though it does, in my naivety I would only expect the imaginary curve" .  but $e^{ix}$ is not purely imaginary.  It is complex.  $e^{0i} = 1 = 1 + 0i$ whereas  $e^{i*\pi/4} =\sqrt 1/2 + i\sqrt 1/2$ and   $e^{i\pi/2} = i = 0 + i$. and so on.

Comment: Can you read the tag descriptions? This question has nothing to do with euler's constant.

Comment: I'm on mobile, so no.

Answer (score 2):

The euler-formula states $$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$

$i$ denotes the imaginary unit and $e^{ix}$ is a complex number with real part $\cos(x)$ and imaginary part $\sin(x)$. The graph shows both parts depending on $x$.

Comment: So then there's no way to represent this with only 1 curve?

Comment: There is a way, but only the interval $[0,2\pi]$ will be visible ($\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are both periodic and therefore, the points repeat forever). The curve is the unit circle (radius $1$, mid-point origin)

Comment: It is only one curve technically, but to display it as one curve would require three or four dimensions (three if domain is only real numbers, four if domain is all complex numbers)

Comment: "So then there's no way to represent this with only 1 curve"  No.  Because a complex number is two -dimensional.  A graph needs dimensions for both input and output.  So this has 1 dimension for input and 2 dimensions for output.  So you need 3 dimensions to properly graph it.

Comment: ... Oh... maybe I should point out as Peter and JMoravitz is that this *is* a single 2- dimensional curve in 3-dimensional space.  I kind of don't want to get into the definition of "curve" and the definition of dimensions of the surface of a curve inside a higher dimensional space but... well....  a "normal" graph of $y = f(x)$ graphed as $(x,f(x))$ is a 1-dimensional graph in 2-dimensional space.  $(y,z) = f(x)$ graphed as $(x, f(x)_real,f(x)_imaginary)$ is a 2-dimensional graph in 3-dimensional space.

Comment: DOH!  It's a 1-dimensional curve in 3-dimensional space.  If you actually graphed it in 3-space is would be a spiral circling around the input axis.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it's because the function $e^{ix}$ has both real and imaginary part. It can't be plotted by just one curve, since it takes a one-dimensional input and gives a two-dimensional output.

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^{ix}$ is complex, we can write $e^{ix} = a + bi$ for some choices of $a$ and $b$.  Wolfram Alpha will plot the curve for the real part $a$ and imaginary part $b$ on the same coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$ which is a complex number, $z$.  $z$ can be written as the ordered pair $z =(\cos x, \sin x)$ where the first term is the Re(z) real part of the imaginary number and the second term is Im(z) the imaginary part of the complex number.

$f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C$

$f$ takes a single real value $x$ as input and outputs a complex value.  Complex numbers are 2-dimensional and have a purely real component and a purely imaginary component.

A "regular" real valued function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ can be graphed in two dimensions, as a set of $x,y$ coordinates where $x$ is the input mapped to a single $y$ output.  To be whimsical, imagine $y$ is the altitude of a mountain climber and $x$ is the time.  $y = f(x)$: the graph would plot the height of the mountain climber at every point of time.

A complex function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C$ also takes a single dimensional value $x$ as input and outputs a single $a + bi$ output but now the output is two dimensional.  If $y = f(x)$ was a graph of a mountain climber and her altitude.  Then $a + bi = (a,b) = f(x)$ is a graph of an ant running around on a table-- not only does the ant go up and down, it also goes left and right.  The graph would be a single curve following the time $x$ but sometimes the ant goes up the computer screen, sometimes down, sometimes it goes forward out of the screen toward the reader, and sometimes it recedes backwards behind the screen.  The path of a mountain climber is a string on a page but the path of the ant is a wire twisted up and down, in and out of the page.

So to plot it when Wolfram only have one dimension available to it, Wolfram plots simple the Re(z) component in one color, and Im(z) component in another.  If you wanted to see how this looks in actual 3-D space you can imagine super imposing them.  Imagine the red goes up and down.  But the blue goes forward (off the screen) and back (behind the screen).  The result will be simple a point circling (very literally and perfectly) around the x-axis.

Seriously. That *is* what the graph of $e^{ix}$ would be.  It's a circle starts and (0,1) and then circles in a regular period around the x-axis as the center of the circle moves along the $x$ axis.

So that's that.....

But, since you didn't ask....

Consider a function $f: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb R$ or worse yet $f: \mathbb C \rightarrow C$.  That is $z = f(x,y)$.  Here the *input* is 2-dimensions that the output is a single dimension.  This is a different story altogether.  In this case the input isn't single variable such as time but a two-component piece of data, such as ... a position on a map with a longitude and latitude.  The output can be single dimension output such as altitude.  This graph will not be a single 1-dimensional wire path but a .... 2-dimensional surface.  Imagine a graph of the mountain altitude of the United States based on longitude and latitude.  The graph would, quiet simply, be a topo representation of the surface of the United States.  Wolram would not be able to represent this in two colors.  Instead Wolfram would (and probably does) represent this as a three-dimensional perspective drawing.

$f: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ for (example $f(x,y)= e^x*e^{iy}$ is ... a real problem.  It simply requires 4-dimensions.  The graph is still a two-dimensional surface but bent in 4 dimensions.

So what happens in Wolfram if you graph:

$f(x,y) = ||e^{x + iy}||$

$f(x,y) = e^{x + iy}$?